# Relationg between tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables in my DB.

**Person**

- id int(11) primary key A_I,
- fName varchar(30),
- lName varchar(30)

**Details**
`which holds detail information about the person`

- id int(11) primary key A_I,
- gender varchar(30),
- email varchar(30),
- age varchar(30)

My question is how can i make a relation between the two and a trigger when deleting a person from Person table also to delete his/her detailed information from Details?
Thanks

Comment: How do you store person id in detail table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways it could be done either by setting a foreign key constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE`
Now looking at the schema I do not see you are storing the person id in the detail table.

You may need to add a column as `person_id` in the `Details` table and store the `id` from `Person` table into this table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Here is a **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90293)** how to create foreign key constraint with on delete cascade

Or you can write a trigger to handle it something as

```
delimiter //
create trigger delete_person after delete on Person
for each row
begin
 delete from Details where person_id = old.id ;
end; //

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you don't need 2 tables. Why storing person details in separate table. you can use the same table Person. This is has more sense.
Else if you are really in need to do it like that you have just to add a column "personId" in your person details as a foreign key.
So to get all data of a person you just join 2 tables:

```
Select * from Person p join PersonDetails pd on p.personId = pd.personId
```

Trigger depends on the database that you are using. If you are using SQL Server please refer to this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189799.aspx

For mysql refer to this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html